# ReactJS: Handle Spatial Navigation (Keyboard and Gamepad)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, gamepad

I'm creating this netflix-like app in ReactJS and i need to implement spatial controls: you should be able to navigate the app using keyboard arrow keys (not tab) or gamepad by focusing one element at the time.

This app will run in a webview possibly on any device including TVs and Tablets, so whatever browser-native solution i want to use i need to know for certain that is universally supported.

Is there a reactjs library or a HTML5 Api that provides cross-browsing spatial-navigation using gamepad and keyboard arrow keys?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot post an example because this is broad problem not relative to the specific code i'm working on. But i made my question more direct and specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/dead/react-js-spatial-navigation
It is a wrapper around js-spatial-navigation. I used this in a test tv application and it worked great! It still missing an example and documentation but it`s pretty straightforward.

```
<SpatialNavigation>
 // your components here
 // for a focusable content you can just wrapper it around the
 <Focusable onFocus={event => this.onFocusFunction(event)} onUnfocus={event => this.onUnfocusFunction(event)}>
     // Your focusable content here
 </Focusable>
 // more components
</SpatialNagivation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Mousetrap.js](https://craig.is/killing/mice) to bind and unbind with the arrow keys any actions you need to perform using the lifecycle hooks `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        Mousetrap.bind(theArrowKeyToBind, () => theActionToPerform);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        Mousetrap.unbind(theArrowKeyToBind, () => theActionToPerform);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you should be looking for something abstract other than angularJS or ReactJS library for spatial navigation in your application. Just go through the below library and checkout the given examples in GitHub.
[NaviboardJS](https://github.com/amanboss9/naviboard)

Its simple to use.Include naviboard in the project and give class navigable to desired elements and enclose it within an other element with some id. i.e **ParentElementID**. Check the below e.g.

```
<div class="wrapper" id='ParentElementID'>
  <div class="box navigable">A</div>
  <div class="box navigable">B</div>
  <div class="box navigable">C</div>
  <div class="box navigable">D</div>
  <div class="box navigable">E</div>
</div>
```

After that call the API from your script :

```
naviBoard.setNavigation('ParentElementID')
```

The view will be navigable and would be available for accessing through keyboard arrow keys.

Library provides other promising API's as well for other use cases.

Check out the example link:

https://jsfiddle.net/amanboss9/zv5hocxq/2/embedded/result

Comment: Is the latest edited one isn't enough ? It do have usage note and example fiddle now. Not sure if it still should be downvoted for no reason.